# How to extend Google Plus access_token expire_time?

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I've wrote my own Google Plus library for PHP and it works successfully so far with one problem that I can't extend expire_time of a access token. I need to use it for further proccessing which I can't expect user to login again to renew it.

What I want to do is to get a G+ Page's following count. I telling you this because if there's another way to get it then I won't be needing APIs.

If not then take a look at what I've got so far:

This is my login URL generator:

```
    public function generateLoginUrl()
    {
        $arr = array(
            "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.".implode(".", Config::$scopes)."",
            "state" => "generate_a_unique_state_value",
            "redirect_uri" => Config::$redirect_uri,
            "response_type" => "code",
            "client_id" => Config::$client_id,
            "access_type" => "offline"
        );

        $oauth_url  = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?".http_build_query($arr);

        return $oauth_url;
    }
```

and here is access token generator:

```
    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        $post = array(
            "code" => $_SESSION["code"],
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "redirect_uri" => Config::$redirect_uri,
            "client_id" => Config::$client_id,
            "client_secret" => Config::$client_secret
        );

        $result = $this->createRequest("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", $post);
        $result = json_decode($result);

        $_SESSION["instagram_token"] = $result->access_token;
        unset($_SESSION["code"]);
    }
```

what I got from getAccessToken is a example like this:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'access_token' => string 'ya29.VAHbw-eZNhhrvJC8JLGuTwAuRyBfqEf9lA_lPC5gcBMvYINsz9nUJyw5-nEqHyA' (length=83)
  public 'token_type' => string 'Bearer' (length=6)
  public 'expires_in' => int 3599
  public 'id_token' => string 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlMDYzZGUwYzlmNjY4NmRlYjY2ZTc0NTRiMzIwMWMxMTE0ZWJhNmUifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTA0OTE3NDIxMDA2NTYyNjIxODA5IiwiYXpwIjoiNzc2OTUiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXVkIjoiNzc2OTU1MjgyODA3LXZvOWk4b2U5NXUyYzY5MW9scnFoaG51N3I5bjE3NjRjLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxN'... (length=719)
```

as you can see above that the access_token I got is expires in 1 hour but I have to regularly check page follower or "circled" count so I need an endless access token or expanded one.

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation for the api. Most google apis explain this well. What you need is to save the refresh token serverside so when the access token expires you can generate a new one. The docs explain how to do this by requesting access "offline" in the flow which gives you also a refresh token only the first time you get it after the user authorized. Post updated code if you still have issues using a refresh token.

Answer (score 5):

expires_in will never be any larger than one hour. What you need to do is [request offline access with access_type=offline](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) and then [use the refresh_token to request a new access_token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) when the access_token expires.

The refresh token will be good as long as [the user](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en) or [you](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) do not revoke your client's access.